# How to make header of GridView to have columnspan?

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-8

I have the following where the white rectangles are GridViewItems and 'Abilities' is the header.

[image: White rectangles are GridViewItems and 'Abilities' is the Header]

How can I make the header be above all the columns?

My Code in short:

```
<GridView Header="Abilities" Margin="0" SelectionMode="None" >
<GridViewItem></GridViewItem>
<GridViewItem></GridViewItem>
<GridViewItem></GridViewItem>
<GridViewItem></GridViewItem>
<GridViewItem></GridViewItem>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two choices:

```
<GridView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="400" Height="400" Header="Abilities">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" Width="400" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridViewItem/>
    <GridViewItem />
    <GridViewItem/>
    <GridViewItem />
    <GridViewItem />
    <GridViewItem />
</GridView>
```

Or, also

```
<Grid Width="400" Height="300">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextStyle}" Text="Abilities" Margin="0 20" />
    <GridView Grid.Row="1">
        <GridViewItem />
        <GridViewItem />
        <GridViewItem />
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting your header outside the `GridView`

```
<TextBlock Text="Abilities"/>

<GridView Margin ="0" SelectionMode="None" />
    <GridViewItem></GridViewItem>
    <GridViewItem></GridViewItem>
    <GridViewItem></GridViewItem>
    <GridViewItem></GridViewItem>
    <GridViewItem></GridViewItem>
</GridView>
```